# KeyCode for Windows Key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

Is there a `keyCode` for the Windows key or a way to detect when it is pressed with Javascript or jQuery?

I've dug through StackOverflow and have found how to detect  <kbd>command</kbd> for Mac and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> for Mac and Windows, but can't find any solutions for detecting when the user presses Windows Key. Not sure if it's just a `metaKey` like <kbd>command</kbd> is but represented by the Windows Flag, or if it's even detectable at all.

Comment: So, this button triggers a windows menu and leaves focus from the browser.. I'm not sure if it's possible. But why do you need this? maybe you can handle otherwise.

Comment: You can try 91 or 92 (right and left button) but I'm not sure it will work

Comment: On a related note: if you happen to use jQuery UI be aware that it provides a (limited) convenience map of key names to keycodes at `$.ui.keyCode`. For example you can check `$.ui.keyCode.DOWN` instead of `40`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VK_LWIN
0x5B - Left Windows key (Natural keyboard) **EDIT:** This explains Ed's answer as hex `5B` is `91`

VK_RWIN
0x5C - Right Windows key (Natural keyboard)

**SOURCE:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, per wikipedia:

> The Windows key can also be used on other operating systems.
>
> On Unix and Unix-like operating systems, it is sometimes called "Meta"
>    or "Super".

**SOURCE:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key#Use_with_non-Microsoft_operating_systems

Answer (score 7):

I ran the following js and got 91 when pressing windows key.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt){ 
    console.log(evt.keyCode);
}
```

Comment: Just FYI I ran it on a Mac and the Command/Super key returns `224`

Comment: I guess 91 is correct code for the "Windows" key, on non-Mac keyboards.  The Mac "meta" key is an entirely different key.