# Preferred way of responding to a keyboard shortcut in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keyboard-events

The Internet is full of ideas on this one, but many of them are dated, and many of them are platform specific.

If I want to respond to a keyboard shortcut for save (<kbd>⌘S</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>control-S</kbd> on Linux/Windows), I know I can try something like this:

```js
document.onkeypress=doit;
function doit(event) {
    if(event.metaKey||event.ctrlKey) {
        switch(event.key) {
            case s: doSomething();
                break;
            //  etc
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the `metaKey` should only work on Mac, while `ctrlKey` should only work on Linux/Windows. Also, I can’t find a simple answer to whether I should use the `keypress` event or `keyup` or `keydown`.

The question is, what is the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: Why is is a problem?  Those properties are defined by the event and exist on all browsers that implement the spec, regardless of platform.  Either way, `keypress` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event), so you'll want to use `keyup`/`keydown`, and really the only difference is preference.  If you're implementing chords, you will probably want to react to both `keydown` and `keyup`

Comment: sorry if am wrong but maybe you can Detect device type and if device is mac assgin metaKey ig...

Comment: @Tibrogargan For example `windows-s` opens up a search while `⌘-s` means save. I should be able to let the windows key do what Windows users expect.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks for the note on `keypress` being deprecated. That simplifies the choice a little.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a solution.

- As @Tibrogargan mentions, `keypress` is deprecated, so I should use `keydown`.
- Although Windows identifies the <kbd>win</kbd> as the meta key, it doesn’t appear to trigger the property (see [How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript#answer-3922353))

Using that, I can use something like:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown',doit);
function doit(event) {
    if(event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
        switch(event.key) {
            case s:
                doSomething();
                event.preventDefault();     //  Don’t Save
                break;
            //  etc
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn’t distinguish when a Mac user presses <kbd>ctrl-s</kbd>, but any Mac user who does that should expect a surprise.

Comment: The windows key isn't triggering the property because the operating system is handling it (and effectively does `event.preventDefault()`).  See [KeyCode for Windows Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458787/2487517)

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Keystrokes](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Keystrokes) helpful. It has no dependencies and is very easy to use.

Using it, your code would look like this:

```js
import { bindKeyCombo } from '@rwh/keystrokes'

bindKeyCombo('super > s', doSomething)
bindKeyCombo('ctrl > s', doSomething)
```